# Is there an equivalent to a jQuery $(this) in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example is there a way to do something like this?

```
# IN CONTROLLER
if Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @tweet = this
  # instead of writing 
  # @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
else
  @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
end
```

Comment: Actually, `find` raises an exception if record is not found, so `else` will never be executed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@tweet = Tweet.find_by(id: params[:id]) || Tweet.new(tweet_params)
```

`find_by` will return `nil` if the record was not found. If `params[:id]` is nil, `find_by` will return `nil` too.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much. An alternative to Dondi Michael Stroma's answer would be to catch the exception:

```
def show
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
end
```

or with a little indirection:

```
def show
  @tweet = find_or_new_tweet
end

private

def find_or_new_tweet # or whatever
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
end
```

Comment: Even better: `before_action :find_or_new_tweet, only: [ :show ]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the tweet to a variable:

```
if @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @tweet.method
else
  @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be one line:

```
@tweet = Tweet.find_by(id: params[:id]) || Tweet.new(tweet_params)
```